# VMware Player cannot start a suspended VM from an SMB shared drive, says "Failed to lock the file"

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, samba, vmware-player

I have a VMware Player VM located in a remote shared folder that resides on a Linux server. On the server side I have set up my file access permissions to the user ID used to open the shared folder, and I ran `chmod -R 0777 *` on the directory where the VMs are located.

Whenever I try to start a suspended VM, I get an error message that says:

```
Could not get snapshot information: Failed to lock the file

Module Snapshot power on failed

Failed to start the virtual machine
```

There are no stale `.lck` files on my VM's working directory, and I have made sure multiple times that the user ID I use to access the SMB share can create and remove files properly. I tried granting total access to all user IDs on the shared folder's properties, Security tab, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Delete the *.lck folders in vmware folder of respective machine and it works fine.

Comment: The OP states `There are no stale .lck files on my VM's working directory`.

Comment: Helped me out..

Comment: @Jonno : Oops, I missed that part but probably it will help others in future. May be OP was checking in wrong directory.

Answer (score 2):

try to delete much space on the disk where the virtual machine is located, I had  the same problem after I moved some big iso files to that disk where the VM was located, then I realized then when i deleted those iso's everything worked fine. I even tested that. I believe that problems are being see if your virtual machine is not preallocated and space left on the drive where the VM currently resides is less. I had observed that behavior already 4 , 5 times. In my case i had a VM with not prealocated disk with the maximum disk space 60 gig, and i had currently used only 20 of those. But the free space that i had left on my drive as only 3,5 gig. After i deleted another 6 gig from my ext3 partition where the Vm was located it worked again.

Comment: That's... probably it. Indeed I have very little space left on the disk where the VM resides. I'll move some files over to another disk, cleanup some files, and see what happens.

Comment: I had 1 or 2 GB space left which was apparently not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by going to the directory path of the virtual machine, and double clicking the `.VMX` file, which is usually the same name as the virtual machine.  This will create a new instance of the same VM.  After that, you can just delete the old instance.  Viola, nothing changes.